# Listen to event in another window

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms

I created a window using `var openedWindow = window.open(...)`.
I have a function which should listen to `click` event for a button in the new window, but it never fires.

Whenever I click `btSearch` button it should open another window and listen for `#submitButton` click event.

```
 btSearch.Attributes["onclick"] = $@"
                                     var openedWindow = window.open(myUrl, "", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,personalbar=no,width=650,height=399,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
                                     window.onModalExit(openedWindow);";
```

Function is `aspx` file

```
function onModalExit(modalWindow) {
    $('#submitButton', modalWindow.document).ready(function () {
        modalWindow.document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
           console.log('RETURNED CORRECTLY');
           alert('Now');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can attach to another window's events, for obvious security reasons, every window is in a dedicated sandbox. You will have to set a communication system between those two, like a websocket or something.

Comment: @sjahan But I have a reference to that window and I can access its DOM and `$('#submitButton', modalWindow.document).ready` works correctly. Only `click` doesn't work.

Comment: the `ready` makes sense, because you ordered the load of a new page, but after that, what happens in that window stays in that window. Else, there would be too many weaknesses because you could cross-site hack every website like that.

Comment: Maybe you could use `postMessage` as with iFrames? I never tried it, but maybe it can do the job in your case!

Comment: Even if you own the window, you don't own the document unless it is same domain as the opener.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 This is exactly the same domain. I redirect to a different page of my website. This is the way it is, because this application was written 15 years ago...

Comment: In that case, mysterious .... Should work. In the old days, I did similar many times but way before jQuery came along. Try POJS.

Answer (score 1):

you can send data from opened window to opener window via `window.opener.postMessage()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Every window in a broswer is "isolated", that is there is no way for you to programaticly effect an other window.

That can be done only by the browser who is managing all those tabs. Or maybe by an installed extension for a browser, i suspect those have the power to inject stuff in the running pages probably

EDIT:

Now since that can not be done directly in any way that i know of, you could maybe:

- Create a polling mechanism on the tab you want to read the value from
- Store the value in some kind of server ( database, in-memory of a back-end etc )
- Find a way to associate some kind of ids so you know what to look for.

So you will be transfering the value by taking a long way around PageA -> BackEnd -> PageB.

I am pretty condifent in saying that you can not effect/read from an other tab just by a plain page. You need something of higher layer, like the browser itself, or an extension that has the ability to inject/inspect pages, after a user has agreed to give permissions by installing the extension.

Comment: Do you know if there is any other way to do that? I just need to get a single value.

Comment: ill edit in a minute. Do you "own" both pages views on the 2 tabs? can you write code in both of them i mean? Or do you want to get a value from somebodys elses page?

Comment: Yes, I own both views.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I see to solve your requirement, would be to use [Sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

But for this, you obviously need some kind of backend.